# Angular 8 Metronic binding not updating

Tags: angular, asynchronous, binding, angular8, metronic

I started a project with Angular 8 Metronic.

I have a component with a form. I want spinner appears on submit click and disappear on API response.
Here is a part of the component code :

```js
@Component({
 selector: 'change-password',
 templateUrl: './change-password.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./change-password.component.scss'],
})
export class ChangePasswordComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

 isLoading: boolean = false;
 ...
 submit() {

  this.isLoading = true;
  
  this.utilisateurService
   .changePassword(changePasswordData).pipe(finalize(() => this.isLoading = false))
   .subscribe(() => {});
 }
        ...
}
```

```html
<form class="kt-form" [formGroup]="changePasswordForm" autocomplete="off">
        ...
 <div class="kt-login__actions">
  <button (click)="submit()" 
  [ngClass]="{'kt-spinner kt-spinner--right kt-spinner--md kt-spinner--light': isLoading}">
   Submit
  </button>
 </div>
</form>
```

When I click on submit button, `isLoading` property is updated to `true` and spinner appears.
When `finalize()` executes, `isLoading` property is updated to `false` but spinner do not disappear...

I don't understand.

I tried to use NgZone but same problem.

Any idea ?

**Edit**

I tried with tap and subscribe. Still the same problem. 
Problem is only for rendering. 
If I click on submit button again, `isLoading` property is `false`, as expected. But spinner still running.

Answer (score 1):

You can resolve this problem, in the `app.component.ts` file `changeDetection configuration` set to `Default`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something when the observable completes then use the complete callback instead of finalize:

Answer (score 0):

#### Quick checklist

1. Are you sure `finalize` is running and the boolean is changing?

   [`finalize`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/utility/finalize) is executed when the subscription is **completed**, not just emitting a value. There could be an issue with `this.utilisateurService.changePassword(...)` never completing the observable.
2. Does it work if you change `finalize` to `tap`?

   [`tap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/utility/do) transparently performs actions or side-effects on every emission.

```js
      this.utilisateurService
          .changePassword(changePasswordData)
          .pipe(tap(() => this.loading = false))
          .subscribe(() => { });
```

3. As a last resource: Does it work if you do not use the pipe and change the boolean inside the subscription?

```js
      this.utilisateurService
          .changePassword(changePasswordData)
          .subscribe(() => { this.loading = false; });
```

Even when I work in a project with Angular 8 Metronic, this issue would be Angular not changing the render when a prop changes, that is battle-tested.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
I tried with tap and subscribe. Still the same problem.
Problem is only for rendering. If I click on submit button again, isLoading property is false, as expected.