# Angular binding in Promise not work in ngOnInit

Tags: angular, promise, binding, ngoninit

In Angular, I use a simple function that return a Promise and in 'then' function I change src of an Img html tag.
when I call this function from NgOnInit (or from onclick), html will not update until i force the content to reload by another click on something. but colsole.log work.

```
  click1() {
    this.loadCaptcha();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadCaptcha();
  }

  loadCaptcha() {
    this.apiService.getCaptcha()
      .then((data) => {
        this.image = 'http://....' + data.id;
        console.log(data);
      });
  }
```

```
<img [src]='image' (click)="click1()" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve that,
the problem is a line of code that exists in Metronic template that disabled data binding.
by disabling changeDetection modification, binding worked again.

```
changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this use DomSanitizer

```
 constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }
 
  ngOnInit() {
  this.apiService.getCaptcha()
      .then((data) => {
        let objectURL = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' +  data.id;
        this.image  =this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(objectURL);
        console.log(data);
      });
       
  }
}
```

Hope useful

Comment: i did that too, but it didn't work. i have to click on something like pagination button to view the resutl, in your sample, img element got disable until on click on pagination button.

Comment: i did that in OnClick of a button and have same result. the problem is not related to ngOnInit, that's related to rendering, same question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61655099/angular-8-metronic-binding-not-updating